# custom project creation and user access using sonarqube rest API's

Tags: sonarqube5.3, sonarqube-api

I have my custom metrics and I would like to create my own custom project in SonarQube and push all my custom metrics to Sonar DB via Rest API's.

Also I would like to create a specific user and provide permission only to the custom project.

Please share the steps to achieve it.

Comment: I'm trying in Java.

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpHost target = new HttpHost("localhost", 9000, "http");
   String url = "/api/projects/create";
   HttpPost objPost = new HttpPost(url);
   ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
   postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "customproj2"));
   postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "customproj2"));
   objPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
   HttpResponse httpResponse2 = httpclient.execute(target, objPost);

Comment: With the help of the above code, I'm able to add new project in the sonar database. But the new project name is not reflecting in the sonar home page.

Comment: To bring the name with related metrics in the sonar home page or dashboard, what are all table I have to update further.?